# How to add value to df1 if the observation exists in df2

Tags: r

My df1 has case number (1000 rows), and education industry(binary variable, with Y indicates the case is about education industry). My df 2 only have 100 cases and all these cases are in the education industry. So I want to add Y to df1's education industry, if the case number shows in df2.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: If I understand you, I think you're talking about merging data frames. Have a look at the `merge` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/merge

Comment: Seems like a ``merge()``. Would you mind to put a sample of your data to be sure?

Comment: Maybe `i<-df1$number %in% df2$number;df1$industry[i]<-Y`?

Comment: Hi, everyone, thank you for your help!!!

Comment: I want to clarify here: what I mean is if the case number exists in df2, then I would replace the value of that case number in df1. The method I figured out is very similar to Rui's: df1$education <- ifelse(df1$CASENUMBER %in% df2$CASENUMBER, "Y", df1$education)